# SSH ForceCommand for shell while keeping regular login and remote command execution possible

Tags: ssh, remote, sshd, ssh-config

How can I run/tweak this command and while using ForceCommand to give this user their shell?

Client Command

`(cat ./sudoPassword ./someCommandInput) | ssh user@ip "sudo -Sp '' someCommand"`

Server sshd_config

`ForceCommand /bin/bash`

The behind the scenes restriction is that ForceCommand needs to be the mechanism that gives this user a shell, in addition to the command above a typical `ssh user@ip` needs to work too.

I have tried various configurations such as

```
ForceCommand /bin/bash -ic $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ls
ForceCommand /bin/bash -s < $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
ForceCommand /bin/bash -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

I've also tried messing around with the client command, giving ssh options like -tt but I can't seem to find the right configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a wrapper script as the `ForceCommand`. Something like this script (say, saved at `/usr/local/bin/myshell`):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

if [[ -n $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]] # command given, so run it
then
    exec /bin/bash -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
else # no command, so interactive login shell
    exec bash -il
fi
```

In action:

```
% grep ForceCommand -B1 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Match user muru
    ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/forceshell
% ssh muru@localhost
$ ls
Desktop   Documents   Downloads   Music   Pictures   Public   Templates   Videos
$ logout
Connection to localhost closed.
% ssh muru@localhost echo foo
foo
% ssh muru@localhost echo '*'
Desktop   Documents   Downloads   Music   Pictures   Public   Templates   Videos
```