# Using ssh authentication with a custom application

Tags: configuration, openssh

I have a custom command line script that I want the users to access over SSH. For example when the user logs in with `ssh user@server` the user should be able to interact with the command line application instead of directly accessing `/bin/bash` (or any other shell).

Are there any configuration changes that should be done to achieve this with OpenSSH?

Comment: [This Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526848/ssh-forcecommand-for-shell-while-keeping-regular-login-and-remote-command-execut) may be useful in accomplishing your objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sshd_config's `ForceCommand` is what you're looking for.

Also, caveat: you say it's a shell script, so no matter what you do, it will still be executed by a shell. This need not be problematic, but it certainly means you need to think about what you do with user input – e.g. `eval`'ing it should be out of the question.